# Date within span during runtime

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to output a date within a span using React. I would like to build this dynamically. Unfortunately that doesn't work

```
   let datum = {`<span>${i} .  ${d.getMonth()} .  ${d.getFullYear()}</span>`}
```

Comment: Please specify _that doesn't work_.

Comment: React puts a red line under the first span with the note:
A property assignment was expected.ts(1136)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React (or JSX) use [JSX syntax](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html):

```
let datum = <span>{i}. {d.getMonth()}. {d.getFullYear()}</span>
```